# remove object from array in swift 3.0

Tags: swift, uitableview, checkbox

I am using checkbox in UITableViewCell. Getting crash while removing from array.

Below is my code for reference:

```
@IBAction func btnCheckBoxClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (sender.isSelected == true)
    {
        let selected = selectedFlights[sender.tag]

        for flight in selectedFlights {
            if flight === selected {
                self.selectedFlights.remove(at: sender.tag)
            }
        }

        sender.isSelected = false;
    }
    else
    {
        selectedFlights.append(allFlights[sender.tag])
        sender.isSelected = true;
    }

    tableViewAirports.reloadData()
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Which line is causing the crash? What is the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get selected data from allflights array not from selectedFlights

```
        let selected = allFlights[Indexpath.row]
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to tell `tableview` to remove rows as well.
right after you remove from your array

```
 if let cell = sender.superview?.superview as? CellView {
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
         print(indexPath.row)
          //if the above prints the row then execute the following line
        self.selectedFlights.remove(at: indexPath.row)  
    }
```

Comment: I just need to change checkbox image.. my problem is in below line of code                 self.selectedFlights.remove(at: sender.tag)

Comment: Exc_BAD_INSTRUCTION in this line let selected = selectedFlights[sender.tag]

Comment: same issue crash at this line self.selectedFlights.remove(at: indexPath.row)
 now

Comment: Did it print the row before giving crash?

Comment: row is 1 but array count is 1 that's the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149071/discussion-between-sahil-manchanda-and-user2931321).

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 3.0

Please try this, do not reload all tableview. just remove that cell.

Tableview Method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! cell
        cell.btnCheckBoxClicked.accessibilityElements = [indexPath]
        cell.btnCheckBoxClicked.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self. btnCheckBoxClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        return cell
    }
```

Button Action

```
@IBAction func btnCheckBoxClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
   let Indexpath = sender.accessibilityElements?.first as! IndexPath
        
   let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: Indexpath) as! cell
    if (cell.btnCheckBoxClicked.isSelected == true)
    {
        let selected = selectedFlights[Indexpath.row]

        for flight in selectedFlights {
            if flight === selected {
                self.selectedFlights.remove(at: Indexpath.row)
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [Indexpath], with: .fade)
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        selectedFlights.append(allFlights[Indexpath.row])
        cell.btnCheckBoxClicked.isSelected = true;
    }
}
```